# MAGMI terribly slow after server migration

Tags: performance, magmi

We've just migrated a site with MAGMI to a new server environment and MAGMI is now terribly slow. What used to complete in 90 seconds now takes hours upon hours to complete. We're only getting about 175 recs/min. Any ideas what might be going on? On the MAGMI page there seems to be at least a few other people that have experienced the same issue. Seems to happen after a server migration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try truncating the logs? It really helps sometimes(depending on their size)
 The last four might be what you actually need to truncate, but usually from time to time it's ok to clear the others too: log_url, log_url_info, log_visitor, log_visitor_info, **dataflow_batch_import, dataflow_batch_export, index_event and report_event**.

Answer (score 0):

Sinner,

Thanks for your reply. We tried those but to no avail. We did figure it out though. Turns out just a few settings in combination made the difference:

PHP CONFIG SETTINGS

```
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 1024M => 1024M
```

OTHER SETTINGS
Added `TTF` and `GETTEXT`. Not sure why those helped but it did.